# Magento 2: Cutom product attribute is not available for lyered navigation

Tags: magento2, layered-navigation, custom-attributes

I have created product attribute using following code. But attribute is not available in layered navigation filter.

```
$eavSetup->addAttribute(
            \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY,
            'custom_dropdown',
            [
             'type'                    => 'varchar',
             'backend'                 => '',
             'frontend'                => '',
             'label'                   => 'Course Location',
             'input'                   => 'select',
             'class'                   => '',
             'source'                  => '',
             'global'                  => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
             'visible'                 => true,
             'required'                => true,
             'user_defined'            => true,
             'default'                 => '',
             'searchable'              => false,
             'filterable'              => false,
             'comparable'              => false,
             'visible_on_front'        => true,
             'used_in_product_listing' => true,
             'is_used_in_grid'         => true,
             'unique'                  => false,
             'apply_to'                => '',
            ]
        );
```

I have searched in back end there is no `Use In Layered Navigation` option available. This attribute is previously added and lot of data is filled for the same. Now requirement is to show this attribute in layered navigation.

Comment: Use in Search Results Layered Navigation to Yes

Answer (score 1):

Please Try This code to add Product attribute to Programatically . with possible options.

```
$eavSetup->addAttribute(
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY,
    'custom_dropdown',
    [
        'type' => 'varchar',
        'label' => 'Custom Dropdown',
        'input' => 'multiselect',
        'required' => false,
        'backend' => 'Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Backend\ArrayBackend',
        'global' => Attribute::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
        'visible' => true,
        'user_defined' => false,
        'searchable' => false,
        'filterable' => true,
        'filterable_in_search' => true,
        'comparable' => false,
        'visible_on_front' => false,
        'unique' => false,
        'group' => 'General',
        'is_used_in_grid' => true,
        'is_visible_in_grid' => false,
        'is_filterable_in_grid' => true,
        'system' => 0,
        'label' => [
            'values' => [
                'Gluten',
                'Soy',
                'Otion1',
                'Otion2',
                'Otion3',
                'Otion4',
                'Otion5',
                'Otion6'
            ]
        ]
    ]
);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this attribute is previously added and lot of data is available for the same. I just want to show this attribute in layered navigation.

Comment: I want to show existing attribute type in layered navigation rather than creating one.

Comment: OK No Problem..

Answer (score 1):

**Follow This Step :-**

> **1.** Navigate to `Stores > Attributes > Product in Magento admin panel`.
>
> **2.** Search for the needed attribute `(the attribute you want to add to the layered navigation)` **and click on it to Edit it**.
>
> **3.** In `Storefront Properties tab > Use in Layered Navigation select Filterable (with results)`.
>
> **4.** Set `Use in Search Results Layered Navigation to Yes`.
>
> **5.** Press the `Save Attribute button` and perform the same changes for all the needed attributes.
>
> **6.** In order the layered navigation to appear on category pages you need to perform the following for each category:
>
> - **Open `Products > Inventory > Categories` and select the category to edit.**
> - **In the `Display Settings tab > Is Anchor select Yes.`**
> - **Click on the `Save Category.`**
>
> **7. To make the changes appear on the store, make sure to `reindex your store.`**

[Magento 2. How to Display Product Attributes in Layered Navigation](https://zemez.io/magento/support/how-to/magento-2-how-to-display-product-attributes-in-layered-navigation/)